# Mysql Query Divide column by 100

Tags: mysql

I have columns being stored in a table as the regular pecent significant figures as floats.(e.g 99.9) I would like to divide them by 100 so they are in they are in raw data form. (e.g) .999

What is the query I would have to write for this ?

I've tried this and nothing seems to change.

UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name`=[value/100]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

update table_name set column_name = column_name / 100;

Comment: Correct if column is of numeric type

Comment: This is course if you permanently want to change the values.  You could also divide the values by 100 in a Select statement as well. Like SELECT column_name/100 as raw_pct FROM table_name.

Comment: I have tried this query in phpMyAdmin, but nothing seems to change or any error is returned. This seems like a very simple query, but yes I'd like to permanently change the values.

Comment: @lifeinthefridge: do a `SELECT`, you'll see your values have all been updated.

Comment: Should the fact this column's data type is float effect anything?

Comment: It works even if the column is not of numeric type but the value is a correct number. I tested it on a text column.

Answer (score 1):

This is very very simple query you can do calculation also in query

```
UPDATE table_name SET percent=percent/100 ;
```

You can do simple calculation like addition,subtraction,multiplication and divide just you do as usual

Comment: Where is "GROUP BY" involved?

Comment: I dont see the link's relevancy and why you would want to divide by 100 everytime you select instead of permanently set the value.

Comment: It is not involved but for user's knowledge

Comment: @MrAzulay i didn't noticed for UPDATE query

Comment: The link is not relevant to the current problem. It will just confuse the OP.